# why is the same objects method called twice?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been doing c++ self study after taking two semesters of Java.

Below is a simple program which builds fine, but when I run it I get gradeBook2s displayInfo() method called twice. I'm sure its something basic I am missing, but any ideas why?

```
//GradeBook.h
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

string courseName;
int courseGrade;


class GradeBook {
public:
    GradeBook(string name, int grade) {
        setCourseName(name);
        setCourseGrade(grade);
    }

public:
    void setCourseName(string name) {
            courseName = name;
    }

public:
    string getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

public:
    void setCourseGrade(int score) {
                courseGrade = score;
            }


public:
    int getCourseGrade() {
        return courseGrade;
    }

public:
    void displayInfo(){
        cout << "Course Name: " << getCourseName()
            << "Course grade: " << getCourseGrade()
            << endl;
    }
};


//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"

int main() {
    GradeBook gradeBook1("Calculus 2", 90);
    GradeBook gradeBook2("Chemistry", 80);

    gradeBook1.displayInfo();
    system("pause");
    gradeBook2.displayInfo();
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Look at some real C++ code to get a feel for C++ style. This is Java code written in C++.

Comment: granted, but I'm following C++ How to Program Deitel, Deitel.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is that you are saving the variables `courseName` and `courseGrade` as global variables. Because of this, you are overwriting the previous class instance's data with the current, in this case, Chemistry. What you need to do is move the declaration of `courseName` and `courseGrade` inside the accessor `private` inside the class, like this:

```
class GradeBook {

private:
string courseName;
int courseGrade;

public:
//put your functions here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The locations where the code stores values is global, so all instances will appear the same.